# Positional Accuracy of linear features using buffers in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I am kind of lost on how to go about this, but I have two vector shape files of a road and want see how accurate they are by estimating the positional accuracy. The files are actualRoad as the true road and testRoad is a generated road. I want to create a buffer around the actualRoad with a width of x amount on both sides so I can calculate the proportion of the buffer intersecting to the testRoad file. I will have to loop through this process in order to increase the x width of the buffer on both sides until I get close to 99% of the testRoad file intersected with the buffer. To do this, I want to create a table in arcpy with columns of increasing buffer width, length of road within the buffer, and % of testRoad in the buffer. The table should show a new row for each iteration the actualRoad buffer gets larger until 99% or prop .99 intersects the testRoad.

My issue is trying to get the loops in working order where the script can go through both files, compare the two shapefiles and properly execute the buffer and calculate the % intersected.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

import os

path = 'C:/filepath'
env.workspace = path

#import files into list
#actual and test, both end in .shp
linelist = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".shp")]
print(linelist)

#create an empty table for info
table = 'outputTable.dbf'
#add the appopriate table attributes: buffer width, length of road, 
#buffer width, % of road shapefile in buffer
arcpy.CreateTable_management(path, table)

arcpy.AddField_management(table, "Buffer_Width", "FLOAT", 10, 1)
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "Length_Road_Buffer", "FLOAT", 8, 1)
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "%_Road_in_Buffer", "FLOAT", 8, 1)

tableCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, ["Buffer_Width", 
"Length_Road_Buffer", "%_Road_in_Buffer"])

for r in linelist:
  bufferWidth = 0 #reset buffer between files
  lenRoad = 0 #reset road length between files

   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r, ["SHAPE@LENGTH"])as cursor:
      #proportion of intersect between bufferWidth and lenRoad need to be 
      #<.99 
      with a while loop
        #buffer analysis(road in question(acutal or test), bufferName, r)
         ##bufferList.append(b)

       #calculate intersection
       for r in cursor:
         #twidth
         bufferWidth += r[0]
         lenRoad +=1
   outrow = [bufferWidth, lenRoad]
   tableCursor.insertRow(outrow)

del tableCursor
```

Comment: There's not much actual code to work from here.. I think the first step is to decide how big your increments will be and then use a range, like for dist in range(0,VeryLarge,Increment): then buffer (to r'in_memory\buff' perhaps) and then clip the testCoast (not a feature class at the moment), calculate the geometry, use summary statistics to sum up the lengths (faster than search cursor) and compare the statistic value to the sum of the lengths before the clip * .99, if you have >= sum length you've hit your 99% in witch case you want to call *break* to exit the loop.

Comment: What is the purpose/intent of your comment `#import files into list`?  You seem to be dealing with just two shapefiles and for those you have string variables holding their full path.  At the moment it looks like you are asking multiple unmarked questions about how to get from where you are with a few lines of code to what you want in your completed code.

Comment: The question has been updated to hopefully be more clear.